# MIPS branching always the same

Tags: mips

So with this MIPS code I'm trying to get a users input of a tree size they would like and the output is the cost. 199 for > 8, 99 >= 6, 69 >= 3, 39 >= 0, and just a phrase saying positive only for a negative input.

My problem is that no matter the input, the program always spits out 69, whats wrong?

```
    #data declarations: declare variable names used in program, storage allocated in RAM
                .data  

    msg1:           .asciiz     "Enter the height of a tree to purchase: "
    msg21:          .asciiz     "The cost: "
    msg22:          .asciiz     " dollars\n"
    msg3:           .asciiz     "\n"
    msgNeg:         .asciiz     "Please enter a positive integer for the tree height.\n"
    big:            .word       8
    med:            .word       6
    small:          .word       3
    negative:       .word       0

    #The program begins after .text
                .text
    main:
                    #Prints first line and receives input
        la $a0, msg1
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        li $v0, 5
        syscall
        la $a0, msg3
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
                    #Stores user input in parameter variable
        move $a0, $v0
                    #Calls cost function to determine cost
        addi $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        jal cost
        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 4
                    #stores returned value to temporary register
        move $t0, $v0
                    #Prints out the cost of the tree
        la $a0, msg21
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        move $a0, $t0
        li $v0, 1
        syscall
        la $a0, msg22
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

                    #return
        jr $ra

    cost:
                    #finds the range of the user value
        la $t6, small
        lw $t7, 0($t6)
        bge $a0, $t7, smTree
        nop
        la $t6, med
        lw $t7, 0($t6)
        bge $a0, $t7, medTree
        nop
        la $t6, big
        lw $t7, 0($t6)
        bgt $a0, $t7, bigTree
        nop
        la $t6, negative
        lw $t7, 0($t6)
        blt $a0, $t7, negTree
        nop
                        #else statement, returns 39
        li $v0, 39
        jr $ra

    bigTree:
                        #first branch, returns 199
        li $v0, 199
        jr $ra

    medTree:
                        #second branch, returns 99
        li $v0, 99
        jr $ra

    smTree:
                        #third branch, returns 69
        li $v0, 69
        jr $ra
    negTree:
                #fourth branch, returns a phrase
        la $a0, msgNeg
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading the user's number:

```
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    la $a0, msg3
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
                #Stores user input in parameter variable
    move $a0, $v0
```

`$v0` will no longer hold the user's value. It has been overwritten with `4`, which corresponds to the case that returns a cost of `69`. You'll have to copy `$v0` to another temporary register right after `syscall 5`.

Also, the logic of `cost` is currently like this:

```
if (value >= 3)
    return 69;
if (value >= 6)
    return 99;
if (value >= 8)
    return 199;
```

So any value >= 3 will return 69, and the larger cases will never be checked. You can just change the order to fix it:

```
if (value >= 8)
    return 199;
if (value >= 6)
    return 99;
if (value >= 3)
    return 69;
```